# How to make Emacs use a different color palette for ansi-term?

Tags: terminal, emacs, colors

I'm using Emacs' ansi-term which supports colors, but the color palette is quite limited, and the strong colors are really hard to read with a dark background.

Can I somehow make Emacs use a different color palette for ansi-term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the customize interface with
<kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-group`<kbd>RET</kbd>`ansi-colors`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Look at the variable `ansi-color-names-vector`.